# Write file in Azure Virtual Desktop

Tags: java, azure

I have a JAR file that generates an XML file. When I run it in my machine, it works fine, but when I upload the JAR file to the AVD (fslogic) and try to create the file, it is generated empty (0kb)

```
try (FileWriter archEscritura = new FileWriter(arch)) {
    BufferedWriter escribo = new BufferedWriter(archEscritura);

    escribo.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n");
    escribo.write("<envio comunicacion=\"2010/052\" institucion=\""+bic.trim()+ "\">\r\n");
    escribo.flush()
    escribo.close()
}
```

Comment: Move the `BufferedWriter` into the resource section of the try-with-resources (just like the `FileWriter` already is), and remove the `escribe.flush()` and `escribo.close()` statements. That likely won't fix the problem, but it will result in better code. In any case, with the information given, we can't help you. Likely you missed some kind of exception somewhere.